# How to safely convert a RAID 0 EBS to just one single EBS in AWS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a windows instance that contain a postgresql database, and it contains a system drive (1 EBS) and a data drive which is run in 4 1TB EBS in RAID 0.

we release we never able to use all the space, so we now want to skrink to a smaller size to one 1.5TB EBS or 4 375GB EBS in RAID 0. We have regular snapshots backup for this instance.

Which will be the safest options? (one 1.5TB or 4 375GB in RAID 0)

How should I migrate the whole data drive from 4 EBS to 1 EBS?

Also in long term, which one is better, in terms of performance and maintenance?

Thank you very much

Comment: probably want to tell us what version of MS Windows and tag the question as MS Windows

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best option is to allocate a new EBS of the size you need. This new EBS will be the final storage.

Once the EBS is initialized and the storage available, then you migrate the database over standard postgreSQL tools (dump and reload?)

To close the activity, you then remove the 4 EBS of 1TB, since you don't need them anymore.

Any other option, won't give you the same level of flexibility and data security (the proposed method is practically risk free)

Comment: I'm quite new to postgresql, the person who build the database is no longer work for us. Can you please give more information on how to perform the migration?

Comment: Hi mate,
it would require a knowledge of your system that I don't have.

Anyway it is not rocket science, I am confident you can make it

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html